# Empty List variable in Python

Tags: python-3.6

I want to create an empty list variable in the function every time when the function is called. I have tried this but not working.

```
def funarr(initarr):
    global count
    arr'count'= []
    arr'count'.append(intarr[:1,:1])
    count += 1

count = 1
```

I want to print output like this:

```
print(arr1)    
print(arr2)   
print(arr3)
```

and so on how many times function called.
(Procedure: when the first-time function is called count var have intially value one so arr'count' (it is wrong syntax for create new empty list) create arr1 first time and second time arr2, arr3, arr4 and so on. Also I want to append the value in newly created list in function)

Comment: This question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to do and what results are you getting?

Comment: I have one array (i.e arr = numpy.array([[2,2],[3,3]]) ) and I want to store arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[1][0] and arr[1][1] value in the list. That's why i created one function for create empty list var (i.e arr1) using count but getting error. Actually main goal is for large array like 8 * 8 used then first i want to store four 4 * 4 array of 8 * 8 in empty list var that i want to create when the function is called. Also further want use this function while four 4 * 4 array give me sixteen 2 * 2 array.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are asking

```
count = 0
def funarr(arr):
        global count
        arr.append([])
        count += 1
        print('function has been called and count is '+str(count))
arr=[]
funarr(arr)
funarr(arr)
funarr(arr)
print(arr)
```

## Adding one more answer after your explanation :

```
def funarr():
    global count
    exec("%s=%s" % ('arr'+str(count),'[]'),globals())
    count += 1

count = 1
funarr()
print(arr1)
funarr()
print(arr2)
funarr()
print(arr3)
```

Comment: No. I want new list var every time function called. Like when the first-time function called the count have initially value 1  so arr'count' list var created (i.e first time arr1) when the second time called empty list arr2 and arr3,arr4, and so on.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Can you please check that and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: The first version also creates a new array every time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `funarr` create lists with unique names each time (this seems like a bad idea), I'd just modify a global.

```
$ cat so.py
_funarrs = []

def funarr(initarr):
    global _funarrs
    _funarrs.append(initarr[:1])

funarr([1, 2, 3])
funarr(["abc", "xyz"])

print(_funarrs)

$ python so.py 
[[1], ['abc']]
```

You can put the new lists in a dictionary or something else if you want.